# Why is a semiprime used as the modulus in RSA?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Technically we can use other composite numbers and as long as we can compute $\varphi(M)$ there is no problem. But then why we restrict modulo to be a semiprime number than any composite number?

Comment: This kind of number is considered to be the hardest case. But I do not know whether this is actually true. ECM can find moderate factors, but I do not know whether P200*P200*P200 would actually be easier to crack then P300*P300

Comment: Hmm... Maybe also because if we have least amount of primes in modulo, the probability of message is not coprime with modulo reduces? So that encryption will be more possibly successful?

Comment: Simply put: By combining two 1000-bit primes, you obtain a 2000-bit modulus. By using ten 1000-bit primes, your modulus grows to less attractive 10000 bits, or by using ten 200-bit primes to still have a 2000 bit modulus, you produce more easily findable factors. Also note that with many prime factors, it is less easy avoidable that a (not necessarily prime) divisor is close to $\sqrt M$, and that would  allow (partial) factorization

Comment: I think this question could be asked at [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What you mention is called multi-prime RSA (RSA-MP), see this nice [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5692/18298) from Cryptography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can use other *squarefree* numbers, not other general composites. See Remark 4.3 and the top of page 10 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/RSAnotes.pdf.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.

Comment: Yeah but we also don't want to create an easy system to break via discrete log.  modulus >> base increases the lower bound on the exponent, small factors in the modulus reduce the system to  find arithmetic progessions the exponent is on. only nearby but large numbers won't give a small multiplier you can attempt to solve for.

Comment: @Roddy Macphee sure, but I wanted to point out the premise of the post had an error: being able to compute $\varphi(M)$ is not sufficient for the math in RSA to work.

Comment: Tempted to fix my own answer, divisibility by 7 sucks. it's not that you can't attack these large numbers with small numbers it's just the results are pitiful to increase the lower bounds on x.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm , probably plays a role.  Some  small factors can affect how quickly this could be done for a number. if I know the modulus has a small factor I can limit the exponent given enough information. For example( however crappy):

$$23547985639486761^x\equiv 5978745931 \bmod 447689046210$$

modulus here is purposedly divisible by 210 . base is 5 mod 7, 0 mod 3, 1 mod 5 and 1 mod 2  making it 201 mod 210. remainder is 4 mod 7, 1 mod 3, 1 mod 2, 1 mod 5 so 151 mod 210.  Still a bad choice by me even after fixing my remainder errors it. cycle length was 6.  so had it hit it would have me check at most every 6 x values.

Another  factor in choosing semiprimes is  additional factors, especially smaller than a given size destroy: $$\varphi(n)=n\prod_{p\mid n,p\in \mathbb{P}} (1-{1\over p})$$ because 2 wipes out half the number, 3 a further sixth if combined, 5 a further two 30ths, 7 a further eight 210ths, so all told they wipe out  162 out of 210, leaving just 48 out of every 210 left. even the cube root of n will only take out a number two-thirds the length of n.

Comment: another is avoiding arithmetic progressions, $a\equiv a+d\pmod {a+2d}$ has a forced multiplier constraint. it must be congruent to additive inverse of the multiplicative inverse of 2 mod a.